# Saving temporary image file in a session

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, image

There is a user registration module which requires users’ logo to upload before register.
I’m facing problem of where to store this uploaded image, because at the time user is uploading the logo, the actual user item is not created.

As solution for that, I can think of saving the uploaded image (until create the actual user item) in a session variable. Will that be a good idea in terms of performance and longtime use of the system?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7150899/asp-net-store-temporary-files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a bad idea. Using session for state will always adversely affect your ability to scale your application and putting large binary blobs into the session will put significant memory pressure on your application. A much better solution would be to store the images into a temp area in the file system and implement a regular sweep function that would clear out any uploaded images that were uploaded by users that didn't convert to registered users (for example, any images more than a day old). Obviously, when a user does complete the registration you would move the image out of temporary storage.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest to use a temperary folder where you store your files giving them some unique names (using Guid, for example).